# Unexpected behavior with rxjs nested observables, window, and scan

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I want to display partial results of an analysis as the data comes in. It would be very inefficient to recompute for each new value (as with 'scan'). However, in this case, I can do the analysis on chunks of the data and combine those results. So I've been using 'window' to break up the data and then 'scan' to combine the results of each window calculation. The result is itself an observable, so it would be very natural to emit that as a nested observable. Also, the next step in the process works really well when consuming observables.

However, I couldn't get this to work as I expected. (I did make it work with an awkward step of turning the inner observables into arrays and later back into observables.) It seems there is something I don't understand about "window" and/or "scan".

Here are two examples that differ in how I produce the nested observable. I'd have expected the following two examples to give the same result, but they do not.

In the first, I create the nested observable directly. In the second, I create it with the window operation. Then, in both cases, I apply the same scan to the nested observable.

This behaves as I expected:

```
rxjs.from([rxjs.from([1, 2]), rxjs.from([3, 4])])
    .pipe(
        ops.scan((acc, curr) => rxjs.merge(acc, curr), rxjs.from([]))
    ).subscribe(win => win.subscribe(
        x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)), e => console.log("error"), () => console.log("|")),
        e => console.log("outer error"), () => console.log("outer |"))
```

With each emitted observable, I see the accumulation of the values of the previous one followed by the new ones. 
`1 2 | 1 2 3 4 |`

I expected this next one to produce the same result, but it doesn't:

```
rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .pipe(
        ops.windowCount(2),
        ops.scan((acc, curr) => rxjs.merge(acc, curr), rxjs.from([]))
    ).subscribe(win => win.subscribe(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)), e => console.log("error"), () => console.log("|")),
        e => console.log("outer error"), () => console.log("outer|"))
```

It seems to effectively ignore the scan operation and emits the original windows,
`1 2 | 3 4 |`

What am I missing? What would a conventional solution to this look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowCount` is using a `Subject` internally. So it creates and returns a Subject and then sends `1` and `2` to it for the first window. With the first `scan` iteration you subscribe to this Subject before `1` and `2` are send and receive those values. For later iterations you subscribe after `1` and `2` were already emitted so you won't receive those values again.

Kind of like:

```js
const { Subject, merge, from } = rxjs

const window1 = new Subject()
const scanResult1 = merge(from([]), window1)
scanResult1.subscribe(console.log)
window1.next(1)
window1.next(2)

console.log('|')

const window2 = new Subject()
const scanResult2 = merge(scanResult1, window2)
scanResult2.subscribe(console.log)
window2.next(3)
window2.next(4)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.5.5/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

**Using bufferCount**

You can simply replace `windowCount` with `bufferCount` to send an array to `scan` instead of a Subject. The code in `scan` can stay the same as `merge` can also handle arrays, but you should use `concat` instead of `merge` if you want to guarantee that the values are emitted in the same order they come in.

```ts
rxjs.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .pipe(
    ops.bufferCount(2),
    ops.scan((acc, curr) => rxjs.concat(acc, curr), rxjs.from([]))
  ).subscribe(
    win => win.subscribe(
      x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)), 
      e => console.log("error"), () => console.log("|")
    ),
    e => console.log("outer error"),
    () => console.log("outer|")
  )
```

**Using windowCount**

You can add a `shareReplay` to your windows, to replay their values to future subscribers. As `windowCount` emits an empty window at the end if the count of the source is divisable by the windowSize, you have to map to your merged observable only when the current window isn't empty. Otherwise you'll get the final result twice.

```ts
from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  windowCount(2),
  scan((acc, curr) => {
    const shared = curr.pipe(shareReplay())
    return shared.pipe(
      isEmpty(),
      switchMap(empty => empty ? EMPTY : merge(acc, shared))
    )
  }, from([]))
)
```

Or

```ts
from([1, 2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  windowCount(2),
  map(w => w.pipe(shareReplay())),
  concatMap(w => w.pipe(isEmpty(), filter(e => !e), mapTo(w))),
  scan((acc, curr) => merge(acc, curr), from([]))
)
```

Comment: That would explain why my workaround, of turning the nested observables into arrays and then back into observables later, would work.

Comment: I don't fully understand your explanation. You said "For later iterations you subscribe after 1 and 2 were already emitted so you won't receive those values again." Yes, in the second iteration I'd expect `curr` to be 3,4, but `acc` should be the result of the first iteration `merge` operation, which should be `1,2`, shouldn't it? Resulting in 1,2,3,4? (Which obviously it isn't. I'm just trying to understand.)

Comment: @EricEvans Yes, in the second iteration `acc` is the result of the first iterations' `merge` operation. But inside this `merge` operation is the **same** Subject that was `curr` in the first iteration. And by the time you subscribe to the result of the second iteration `1,2` have already been emitted on this Subject, so the subscription happens to late to receive `1` and `2`.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. I imagined `merge` as combining the values, but it is combining the two active streams, one of which has already completed. So it is deterministic? I mean, it is not a matter of timing, and could miss more or fewer, it misses exactly the first window, then exactly the second window, etc.?

Comment: I hope I'm not being annoying here, but I want to actually understand this and also understand the intended use. I see that the way I'm using `merge` with `scan`. I was surprised because, if I make a nested observable with `from`, it does work. Even so, is it really the case that the recommended solution is to use Array? The nested observable would work well in my case, if it worked. For one, the operation on the window is the same as the one that combines the window (by design, a monoid), and it includes a groupBy. In my current workaround, I turn it into Array and then back. Seems awkward?

Comment: @EricEvans Yes, to my knowledge it will miss exactly the first window, then the second and so on, because the next `scan` is called after the previous window completed (if you don't work with overlapping windows by providing a `startWindowEvery` value). For the code you posted in your question I would use `bufferCount`.

Comment: If you want to work with `windowCount` you can add a `shareReplay` to your windows, to replay their values to future subscribers. As `windowCount` emits an empty window at the end if the count of the source is divisable by the windowSize, you have map to your merged observable only when the current window isn't empty. Otherwise you'll get the final result twice.